# How Can I embed C or C++ compiler in a Php project

Tags: php, c++

I am working on a Laravel project Where I want to have a `textarea` and a execute `button`. The `textarea` will be used to write C or C++ code and the button will show the output in any place of my website. Is that even possible I don't know may be what I am thinking may be stupid but if its possible I want some suggestion from the experts. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will have to take *some* care that the uploaded code isn't a virus or a program that formats you hard drive.

Comment: It's possible (there's projects like that, e.g. ideone.com).

Comment: Can you please tell me in detail? @hlt

Comment: Just so you know, unless you really know what you are doing, and even then are *really* careful, this can be a *massive* security risk. Allowing people to execute arbitrary binary code gives them, potentially, a lot of control over your system.

Comment: Having said that you this project may be of interest, its fairly mature and has undergone a lot of testing. However you still need to secure the execution environment. https://github.com/Eelis/geordi

Comment: I want something like  [this](http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/declarations-and-initializations/). In the link click on the click on the C compiler option under every multiple choice question. How can I do that I want suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is possible. Text area will not work and I would suggest to use ace editor.

Secondly, PHP do have in-built functions like `system()` , `exec()` and `shell_exec()` and find the details on http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php .

Also, if you are on linux then you can use the g++ compiler to compile the code and make the .out object and then run that object using `shell_exec()` and return the output in the browser and echo it.

But you have to take care of the security issues and anyone can hack your system. Also you have to take care of the resources like CPU and Memory being used by a program.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure about TinyMCE editor. Would recommend you to take a look at the ace editor. https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about

Answer (score 0):

Hei **Bashar the Coder**,

Obviously, you can make your own C, C++, java, python and also others onilne compiler...
First see, **Kinshuk Lahiri** and if you are'nt a boss or security specilist or have a good knowledge on security, please avoid this..

By the way you can make a compiler from this source codes of github..
https://github.com/bhargavgolla/Online-Compiler

Or
https://github.com/apanimesh061/OnlineCompiler

And I think, you can face problems of setup of that pages..
Specilly for C, C++ and for java you've to set your path variable in the system advance option if you are using Windows and if LINUX then follow their instructions....

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how they did it, but if it helps, a good example is [here.](https://onlinegdb.com/online_c++14_compiler) They have a website exactly as you pictured. They also compile C, Java, Python3, and more including HTML, CSS, Javascript, and even Rust. I could go on for hours of how helpful they were. They even have Python modules that you would otherwise have to download with pip.

Comment: The link you give is broken.